# Android studio back goes to splash screen

Tags: java, android

I have created this simple splash screen ;

```
public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish(); } }, 1000);
    }

    }
```

I declared the splash screen to be the first screen that opens like this;

```
   <activity android:name="com.androidhunger.opendagapp.Splashscreen"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"><intent- 
        filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter></activity>
```

After the splash screen my mainactivity opens a fragment with menu code inside of it, but I don't think the problem lays there. My problem is, when I open my app and the splash screen is done, and i've loaded my first screen, when I press back once, it takes me to a blank page. I can't recreate it here with easely, but I hope someone recognizes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clear your activity stack before you start new activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It did not work, I am still able to go back to the blank page. It might help to add that the page that opens when I press the back button is an empty instance of the HomeFragment that I instantly launch when the app starts.

Comment: how did you mark it correct and then it doesnt work ? could you please post your MainActivity.class

Comment: I changed a bit of code so now it does work, I used your code for a part of it. thank you

Comment: You are weclome , could you make it correct again ?